# Rails, Gmail SMTP and failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, gmail

I am trying to set up an action mailer, so people can send a message using contact form on my website.

Here is my configuration for production:

```
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'mydomain.co' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :port           => 587,
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['GMAIL_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'mydomain.co',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

I was trying to test it and the mail is delivered, but after that I immidiately receive a message from "Mail Delivery Subsystem" with a subject "Delivery Status Notification (Failure)".

What is causing this message and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

Mine looks like this

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
:port                 => 587,
:domain               => 'gmail.com',
:user_name            => ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
:password             => ENV["GMAIL_PASS"],
:authentication       => 'plain',
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Also make sure you've enabled "Less Secure Apps" in your Gmail settings: 
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Hope that helps!